# Validation when dynamic choices are set in django forms

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I had a little issue a few hours ago, I wanted to save a form after getting data from a POST submited by the user.

The thing was that I set the choices for my multiple choice select dynamically, I mean, after the `__init__` method was called. Just like a lot of answers in SO suggest.

So the problem arise when the data was cleaned and, since there was no choices at the point the method `clean()` was called I got the normal error 'Select a valid choice. bla, bla, bla'.

EDIT: An example of the problem

The previous code(does not work):

```
class myForm(forms.Form):

    myField = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.some_data = kwargs.pop('some_data')
        super(myForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        dynamicChoices = Objects.objects.filter(some_filter=self.some_data)
        self.fields['myField'] = forms2.MultipleChoiceField(choices=dynamicChoices)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There is no question unanswered. I figured it out by my own but saw so many questions about it and wanted to share this piece of information with everybody.

Comment: So, you should ask a question, add an answer to it and accept it.

Comment: Good idea Krzyzstof, I don't know why I did not do that in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little research and unmeasurable frustration I found a solution.
The clean method was to be called again on the form. And according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) django docs-page the method that could help me is `full_clean()`.

It is good to mention that the dynamic choices I use needed no special validation, the problem was that when the selected choices were compared in the construction of the form after the user submitted them there was no choices assigned to the field.

The code with the `full_clean()` method that makes everything work.

```
class myForm(forms.Form):

    myField = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.some_data = kwargs.pop('some_data')
        super(myForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        dynamicChoices = Objects.objects.filter(some_filter=self.some_data)
        self.fields['myField'] = forms2.MultipleChoiceField(choices=dynamicChoices)

        super(myForm, self).full_clean()
```